# proof that an isometric orthogonal mirroring on R2 has a determinant of -1

Tags: determinant, matrix-equations, isometry

I am asked to prove that an isometric mirroring on a line l through the origin on a 2 dimensional plane of the reals, has a determinant of -1.

First of all, is it true that my book is sloppy here in assuming unstatedly that such a mirroring is given by a matrix? because a determinant is only defined for a matrix right? and there could be some other computational implementation of such a mirroring that doesn't use matrices. Or am I missing something?

Moreover, can I simply assume that the transformation function that gives this mirroring **must** be of the form f(v) = Av, where A is a transformation matrix?

lastly, how does one go about proving this, even assuming that this is indeed the functional form?

Comment: Modulo rotation, the map is given by $(x,  y) \to (x, -y)$. In particular, it's linear.

Comment: The determinant is well-defined for a linear map $f: V \to V$. The induced map $\wedge^n V\to \wedge^n V$, where $n = \dim V$, is a linear map on a $1$-dimensional space and so must be multiplication by a constant (independent of the choice of basis); that constant is by definition $\det f$. The determinant of a matrix comes from treating a matrix as a linear map (after choosing a particular basis, but the determinant itself is independent of that choice, as $\det(h^{-1}gh) = \det g$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y=mx$ be the line, we wanna show several things. First, the map of mirroring is a linear map: this statement is actually much easier to see if we consider the basis $\vec v_1=(1,m),\vec v_2=(-m,1)$ that consists of perpendicular vectors. Then the map is just reflection along the given line (on which $\vec v_1$ lies), so it must be linear since we are just taking a component ($\vec v_2$) of a vector  to its inverse ($-\vec v_2$), which is a linear combination of vectors. Specifically for any vector written as: $a_1 \vec v_1 + a_2 \vec v_2$,

$$T( a_1 \vec v_1 + a_2 \vec v_2)= a_1 \vec v_1 - a_2 \vec v_2$$

---

Then we want to show that the determinant can only be $-1$: consider the linear map as a matrix, thus should have matrix of the form $\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0 \\ 0 &-1\end{pmatrix}$ when respect to the basis. Since determinant is unchanged under change of basis, so it can only be $-1$.